# How to execute db/jpa operations inside quartz context?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quartz

I have this service Scheduling a task:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class PaymentService {

    @Transactional
    public Payment scheduleNewPayment(Payment payment) throws ParseException, SchedulerException {
        Payment.persist(payment);
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(PaymentJob.class)
                .withIdentity(String.format("job%d", payment.id), "payment-job-group")
                .build();
        Date parsed = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(payment.dueDate);
        SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(String.format("trigger%d", payment.id), "trigger-group")
                .startAt(parsed)
                .forJob(job)
                .build();
        SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        scheduler.start();
        return payment;
    }

}
```

And this job:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class PaymentJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println(Payment.count());
    }

}
```

But I can not perform a DB operation inside the Job context (jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext() is null by the way).

I'm running my app with quarkus, the hibernate operation comes from Hibernate Panache and the Scheduler is quartz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use the underlying managed Quartz Scheduler instance  : `@Inject org.quartz.Scheduler` (I suppose you're using the `quarkus-quartz` extension).

The other "problem" is that the default Quartz job factory simply calls `new PaymentJob()` and so no injection/initialization is performed. Quarkus is only using a custom factory for the jobs generated for methods annotated with `@Scheduled`. If you don't need injection then simply remove the superfluous`@ApplicationScoped` from the `PaymentJob` class.

Finally, you need to activate all the necessary CDI contexts manually. It's very likely that the request context is needed. You can copy the following snippet: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/arc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/arc/runtime/BeanInvoker.java#L14-L24 into your `execute()` method.

> jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext() is null by the way

This is really odd. What exception/error do you actually get?

Comment: `jobExecutionContext.getScheduler().getContext()` is not null, sorry. It is empty. I don't get any error, it just return an empty list.

Comment: And thanks for the answer! I could solve my problem activating my request context: `Arc.container().requestContext().activate()` and then get my bean instance: `Arc.container().instance(PaymentService.class)`

Comment: Hi @GabrielCunha ! I'm on the same situation... Would it be possible to share a small code snippet? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You can access the code here: https://github.com/cunhazera/schedule-payment
It's working now.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Gabriel. Very appreciated

Comment: If anyone faces this issue, the snippet by  Martin Kouba (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/arc/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/arc/runtime/BeanInvoker.java#L14-L24) is actually (in the meantime?) implemented, simply adding `@ActivateRequestContext` to `execute()` method should be enough.